# Truncate paragraph first 25 character and hide rest content of paragraph Angular 8

Tags: angular, truncate, string-length

I have paragraph which has more than 100 character. I want first to get load only initial 25 character and hide rest of it. I want to insert "More" link next to 25 character. On click of more link next 25 characters will show with "More" link. On click of more link next 25 characters will show with "More" link like that till end of the paragraph.  Paragraph is dynamically generated and it is inside a table.

I am not sure how to achieve this. Please guide me.

```html
data
rows = [
      {
        ,
        "ID" : "3", 
        "TextContent" : "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text.It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text. It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text.", 
             },
 
       { 
       "ID" : "1", 
       "TextContent" : "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.", 
            }
 ]
 
 <table id="users">
    <th *ngFor = "let column of headers">
        {{column}}
      </th>
      <tr *ngFor = "let row of rows">
          <td>
            {{row.ID}}
          </td>
         
          <td>
            {{row.TextContent}}
          </td>
        </tr> 
      
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to do something like this
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m8hutt?file=src/app/app.component.html

You can use truncate pipe to truncate paragraph to 25 characters and then show/hide full paragraph using a flag variable in row data array

Comment: Hi Zainhassan, i want initially load only 25 characters with more button and while clicking on the more button next 25 characters should show with more button like that till the end of the paragraph. So initially 25 characters, then total 50 characters(25+25 characters) like that. Hope you understand my question. Please let me know if you need more details

Comment: I have updated the code. Let me know if it okay now

Comment: Thanks Zainhassan. This is almost similar to what i want. Only one change required is that, it should not show more button at the end if there is no more that 25 characters. Is it possible to hide the more button at the end?

Comment: Thanks its working. One more question. what is this count: 1 in row array? The data is coming as an API from backend. So not sure i will be able to add that. Is that required?

Comment: you have to add it in data array yourself so that you can keep track of how many characters to show.